# Combining workbooks into one master sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I currently run 2 macros.

1) Takes all csv in my folder and opens them all in one workbook - This works fine.

2) Combines them all into master worksheet.

My issue is with 2. It skips some of the files. It is around 250 csv files I am trying to put into one. Some workbooks will be blank but will still have headers. Headers are all alike.

Here are the codes:

```
Sub Merge2MultiSheets()
    Dim wbDst As Workbook
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim strFilename As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    MyPath = "PATH" ' change to suit
    Set wbDst = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    strFilename = Dir(MyPath & "\*.csv", vbNormal)

    If Len(strFilename) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Do Until strFilename = ""

        Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath & "\" & strFilename)

        Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets(1)

        wsSrc.Copy After:=wbDst.Worksheets(wbDst.Worksheets.Count)

        wbSrc.Close False

        strFilename = Dir()

    Loop
    wbDst.Worksheets(1).Delete

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

and

```
Sub CopyFromWorksheets()
    Dim wrk As Workbook 'Workbook object - Always good to work with object variables
    Dim sht As Worksheet 'Object for handling worksheets in loop
    Dim trg As Worksheet 'Master Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range 'Range object
    Dim colCount As Integer 'Column count in tables in the worksheets

    Set wrk = ActiveWorkbook 'Working in active workbook

    For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets
        If sht.Name = "Master" Then
            MsgBox "There is a worksheet called as 'Master'." & vbCrLf & _
            "Please remove or rename this worksheet since 'Master' would be" & _
            "the name of the result worksheet of this process.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Error"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next sht

     'We don't want screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     'Add new worksheet as the last worksheet
    Set trg = wrk.Worksheets.Add(After:=wrk.Worksheets(wrk.Worksheets.Count))
     'Rename the new worksheet
    trg.Name = "Master"
     'Get column headers from the first worksheet
     'Column count first
    Set sht = wrk.Worksheets(1)
    colCount = sht.Cells(1, 255).End(xlToLeft).Column
     'Now retrieve headers, no copy&paste needed
    With trg.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount)
        .Value = sht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount).Value
         'Set font as bold
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With

     'We can start loop
    For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets
         'If worksheet in loop is the last one, stop execution (it is Master worksheet)
        If sht.Index = wrk.Worksheets.Count Then
            Exit For
        End If
         'Data range in worksheet - starts from second row as first rows are the header rows in all worksheets
        Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, 1), sht.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, colCount))
         'Put data into the Master worksheet
        trg.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
    Next sht
     'Fit the columns in Master worksheet
    trg.Columns.AutoFit

     'Screen updating should be activated
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

My headers go from A3:C3 , the data above is not needed.

Comment: If you are using Excel 2013 or later you might want to look into using Power Query/Get &Transform. It can combine a huge set of .csv's into one sheet without any macro work at all, and is probably going to be a lot faster (assuming you don't actually need every .csv as it's own tab in the workbook as well, which seems like a bad idea).

Comment: @Wedge Im 2010 :( , I guess ill have to get 2013 soon.

Comment: @Wedge Isn't Power Query available in 2010 as a free MS add-in?

Comment: I think it's possible to get it to work in 2010 but isn't officially supported? I don't have 2010 to test anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing unnecessary work by copying CSV sheets into workbook, then copying data to master tab. Just bring in data from CSV directly to pre-loaded Master tab (template).

This code assumes 1 worksheet in workbook that will run code that already has headers defined. See note about adjusting `10` to number of column headers you actually have.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoadCSVs()

Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")

With wsDest

    'clear old data if needed
    If Len(.Range("B2")) Then
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1)).Clear 'removes old data
    End If

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim MyPath As String
MyPath = "PATH" ' change to suit

Dim strFilename As String
strFilename = Dir(MyPath & "\*.csv", vbNormal)

If Len(strFilename) = 0 Then Exit Sub

Do Until strFilename = ""

    Dim wbSrc As Workbook
    Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath & "\" & strFilename)

    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets(1)

    With wsSrc

        If Len(.Range("B2")) Then

            Dim vData As Variant 'load data to variant
            vData = Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1))

            'place on master tab                                                           'adjust to column header length
            wsDest.Range("A" & wsDest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(vData), 10).Value = vData

        End If

    End With

    wbSrc.Close False

    strFilename = Dir()

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: am I supposed to have the worksheet named master in a blank workbook? I have it named master already, then the code executes perfectly but No data is copied into the master. Also there is data like the file name and record count in A1 and A2 , but the headers dont start till A3:C3.

Comment: you'll need to adjust the code to where the headers start. I assumed headers in row 1 with `Intersect(.UsedRange,.UsedRange.Offset(1))`. The idea was to put this code into a workbook with one sheet called `Master` and headers in row 1.

Comment: which intersect is needed to be changed?

Comment: the one assigned to `vData`. Or you can set the range another way as well, if its easier for you.

Comment: Hi Scott, when I change this line to `vData = Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(3))` I am not getting anything. But it works fine when its header in the 1st row  in a sample file and Offset is 1.

Comment: @excelguy - it's hard to really help without seeing sample data. Please try playing around a bit and debugging. What you have written looks correct if your first two rows have data that is not the header.

Answer (score 0):

The index may not be reliable and you likely exit the loop prematurely.

```
For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets

    If sht.Name <> "Master"            
         'Data range in worksheet - starts from second row as first rows are the header rows in all worksheets
        Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, 1), sht.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, colCount))
         'Put data into the Master worksheet
        trg.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
    End If

Next sht
```

Comment: Hi niton, thanks for your answer, I am seeking some code that combines it all. As Scott posted, i am doing unnecessary work by bringing in the csv's into workbook first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this AddIn.  It will do what you want.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

[image]